# How to capture the nested variable in for loop?

Tags: linux, bash

```
> cat script    
copy1=/tmp/a.txt    
copy2=/tmp/b.txt    
dest1=/tmp/c.txt    
dest2=/tmp/d.txt    
for i in `seq 1 4` do ; cp -pr $copy${i}  $dest${i}
done
```

Is the above possible? I wasn't able to `copy file` to `dest files`.

Comment: You should use arrays instead.

Comment: seq(1) is nonstandard, inefficient and useless. For bash2.04+/zsh/ksh93, use `for ((i = 1; i <= 10; i++)); do ...;done`

Comment: For *any* POSIX-compatible shell: `i=1; while [ "$i" le 10 ]; do ... ; i=$((i+1)); done`.

Comment: Hi here one more problem with the cp -pr $copy${i}  $dest${i} , adding two variables as a one variable ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variable reference:

```
for ((i=1; i<=4; i++)); do
   src="copy$i"
   dest="dest$i"
   cp -pr "${!src}" "${!dest}"
done
```

Comment: Thanks yout your quick help, but i tried in your way ,still getting some other errors ,

Comment: small changes done in script , could you please check once

Comment: Thanks a lot master ! Wonderful its working absolutely file :)

Comment: can you explain me what it ${!src} does , why we mentioning ${! variable}

Comment: This is called `indirect expansion` of variable. `${!src}` gets the **value of value** of variable `$src`.